# compute the aggregate delta I.C. for all columns

Tags: php, matrix

1) Given a matrix of cipher-text, i want to calculate the index of coincidence for each column. I want to compare the cipher-text to itself by stacking as is done in this example from wiki: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Index_of_coincidence#Example

I already have the PHP for the general delta I.C and i was thinking that all i probably have to do is change a couple things to get it working can someone help me out with this?

2)I already have the separate PHP script for manipulating text into various blocks but not stacking them as in a matrix.  How can i get the  script (in part 1 above) to test for all possible matrices (assuming the matrices are small).

Here's what I've got so far:

```
<?php
  $showTable = false;
  if (isset($_POST['submitx'])) {
    $showTable = true;
    $ciphertext = strtoupper($_POST['ciphertext']);
    // compress out spaces
    $i = 0;
    $cols = 10; 
    $cells = 1; 
    $compressed = '';
    while ( $ciphertext[ $i ])
    {
        if (( $ciphertext[ $i ] >= 'A' ) && ( $ciphertext[ $i ] <= 'Z' ) ) {
            $compressed .= $ciphertext[ $i ];
        }
        $i++;
    }
    $inLen = strlen( $compressed );

    // text is now collected without spaces in $compressed
    $history=array_fill(0,99,0);
    for ($shift = 1; $shift < 100; $shift++ ) {

        // test coincidence at this shift
        $coinc = 0;
        for ( $i = 0; $compressed[ $i + $shift ]; $i++ ) {
            if ( $compressed[ $i ] == $compressed[ $i + $shift ] ) $coinc++;
        }
        $coef = 100.0 * $coinc / ( 3.85 * ($inLen - $shift));
        $history[ $shift ] = $coef;
    }
      for ( $keyLen = 1; $keyLen < 50; $keyLen++ ) {
        $freqSum = 0.0;
        $index = $keyLen;
        $count = 0;
        while ( $index < 100 ) {
            // step through the history array by stepsize = keyLen
            $freqSum += $history[ $index ];
            $count++;
            $index += $keyLen;
        }
        $freqSum = $freqSum / $count; // average of all the values
        $history[ $index ] = $freqSum; // put it back for later
    }
    }
?>
```